How do we know that a nucleus is in its ground state?
I think this must be a silly question but I would like the opinion of some experts.
A nucleus in excited states usually decay very quickly by isomeric transition, with a half-life of around $10^{-12}$ to $10^{-9}$ seconds. But there are many cases where a nuclide has an isomer which is not known to undergo isomeric transition, especially for odd-odd nuclides:
$\bullet$ $^{180\rm{m}}\rm{Ta}$ is not known to undergo any decay mode;
$\bullet$ $^{176\rm{m}}\rm{Lu}$ has a half-life of $3.664\,\rm{h}$ and a spin of $1^-$ compared to the $3.704\times 10^{10}$-years half-life and the $7^-$ spin of $^{176}\rm{Lu}$, but $^{176\rm{m}}\rm{Lu}$ is not known to undergo isomeric transition to convert to $^{176}\rm{Lu}$;
$\bullet$ There are two states of $^{248}\rm{Bk}$ known, one has a half-life of $23.7\,\rm{h}$ and a spin of $1^-$, the other is only known to have a half-life of $>9\,\rm{y}$ and a spin of possibly $6^+$. We don't know which one has lower energy due to lack of precise measurements, but neither is known to undergo isomeric transition to become the other one.
$\bullet$ There are many odd-odd isomers in the region just above the closed shell $Z=82$, $N=126$, whose isomeric transitions are not known due to alpha decays being too fast.
In conclusion, a nucleus in ground state cannot undergo isomeric transition; a nucleus in excited states is energetically possible to undergo isomeric transition (by definition), but such a process can be very hard to observe, possibly because the spin change would be too high, and/or other decay modes are too fast.
So I would like to know: How do we identify the ground states of nuclides? In other words, a nucleus in its state with the lowest known energy is possibly in its ground state, but perhaps it is also possible that the nucleus can undergo isomeric transition in theory and we haven't yet observe it? So how can we be sure that a nuclide (imagine the familiar ones that appear around us on a large scale) would not turn to be an isomer some day in the future?
